# Handle large bitmap in viewpager inside listview

Tags: android

i have viewpager inside listview,According to requirements all images coming from server so i have to display in viewpager as a listview row,so i am using piccaso library for downloading ,the problem is the images resolution is too high ,when i am trying to scroll listview then it goes out of memory,let me know any better solution ,how can i achieve it smoothly
this is my code

this is my fragment class

```
public class home_fragment extends Fragment {
    Session_manager session;
    ProgressDialog pDialog;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    ArrayList<String> Array_img = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> Array_single_image = new ArrayList<String>();
    SampleAdapter adapter;
    String accestoken;
    String device_id;
    CircularImageView img_profile;
    private Resources mResources;
    ListView Lv;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_activity, container, false);
        Lv = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView);
        mResources = getActivity().getResources();
//        img_profile = (CircularImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView_circular);
//        img_profile.setBorderColor(mResources.getColor(R.color.Loginbg));
//        img_profile.setBorderWidth(5);
//
//        final Bitmap srcBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mResources, R.drawable.avatar_girl);
//
//        // Display the bitmap in ImageView
//        img_profile.setImageBitmap(srcBitmap);
//
//        Paint paint = new Paint();
//
//        // Get source bitmap width and height
//        int srcBitmapWidth = srcBitmap.getWidth();
//        int srcBitmapHeight = srcBitmap.getHeight();
//
//                /*
//                    IMPORTANT NOTE : You should experiment with border and shadow width
//                    to get better circular ImageView as you expected.
//                    I am confused about those size.
//                */
//        // Define border and shadow width
//        int borderWidth = 25;
//        int shadowWidth = 10;
//
//        // destination bitmap width
//        int dstBitmapWidth = Math.min(srcBitmapWidth,srcBitmapHeight)+borderWidth*2;
//        //float radius = Math.min(srcBitmapWidth,srcBitmapHeight)/2;
//
//        // Initializing a new bitmap to draw source bitmap, border and shadow
//        Bitmap dstBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(dstBitmapWidth,dstBitmapWidth, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
//
//        // Initialize a new canvas
//        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(dstBitmap);
//
//        // Draw a solid color to canvas
//        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
//
//        // Draw the source bitmap to destination bitmap by keeping border and shadow spaces
//        canvas.drawBitmap(srcBitmap, (dstBitmapWidth - srcBitmapWidth) / 2, (dstBitmapWidth - srcBitmapHeight) / 2, null);
//
//        // Use Paint to draw border
//        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
//        paint.setStrokeWidth(borderWidth * 2);
//        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
//
//        // Draw the border in destination bitmap
//        canvas.drawCircle(canvas.getWidth() / 2, canvas.getHeight() / 2, canvas.getWidth() / 2, paint);
//
//        // Use Paint to draw shadow
//        paint.setColor(Color.LTGRAY);
//        paint.setStrokeWidth(shadowWidth);
//
//        // Draw the shadow on circular bitmap
//        canvas.drawCircle(canvas.getWidth()/2,canvas.getHeight()/2,canvas.getWidth()/2,paint);
//
//                /*
//                    RoundedBitmapDrawable
//                        A Drawable that wraps a bitmap and can be drawn with rounded corners. You
//                        can create a RoundedBitmapDrawable from a file path, an input stream, or
//                        from a Bitmap object.
//                */
//        // Initialize a new RoundedBitmapDrawable object to make ImageView circular
//        RoundedBitmapDrawable roundedBitmapDrawable = RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(mResources, dstBitmap);
//
//                /*
//                    setCircular(boolean circular)
//                        Sets the image shape to circular.
//                */
//        // Make the ImageView image to a circular image
//        roundedBitmapDrawable.setCircular(true);
//
//                /*
//                    setAntiAlias(boolean aa)
//                        Enables or disables anti-aliasing for this drawable.
//                */
//        roundedBitmapDrawable.setAntiAlias(true);
//
//        // Set the ImageView image as drawable object
//        img_profile.setImageDrawable(roundedBitmapDrawable);






        session = new Session_manager(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        HashMap<String, String> user = session.getUserDetails();
       // img_profile.setImageResource(R.drawable.profile_placeholder);
        // access_token
         accestoken = user.get(session.Acess_Token);


         device_id = user.get(session.device_id);
        new Login().execute();

        return rootView;
    }
    private class Login extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void> implements DialogInterface.OnCancelListener {
        String android_id;
        String myVersion, Hardware;
        JSONObject jsonnode, json_User;
        String str;
        String Name, access_tocken, Ostype;


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            //   mProgressHUD = ProgressHUD.show(HomeActivity.this, "Connecting", true, true, this);
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
            android_id = Settings.Secure.getString(getActivity().getContentResolver(),
                    Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
            myVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE;
            Hardware = Build.MANUFACTURER;
            data.clear();
            Array_img.clear();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // Creating service handler class instance
            publishProgress("Please wait...");

            String Response = makeServiceCall(Constants.Fetch_posts);
            if (Response != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = null;
                    try {
                        jsonObj = new JSONObject(Response);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    // Getting JSON Array node
                    // JSONArray array1 = null;
                    str = jsonObj.getString("status");
                    if (str.contentEquals("true")) {
                        //jsonnode = jsonObj.getJSONObject("data");
                        JSONArray array1 = null;
                        array1 = jsonObj.getJSONArray("data");

                        // looping through All Contacts
                        for (int i = 0; i < array1.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject c = array1.getJSONObject(i);

                            String id = c.getString("id");
                            String user_id = c.getString("user_id");
                            String caption = c.getString("caption");
                            String Name = c.getString("name");
                            String username =c.getString("username");
                            String media1_thumb_url = c.getString("media1_thumb_url");
                            String media2_thumb_url = c.getString("media2_thumb_url");
                            String media3_thumb_url = c.getString("media3_thumb_url");
                            String media4_thumb_url = c.getString("media4_thumb_url");
                            String media1_url = c.getString("media1_url");
                            String media2_url = c.getString("media2_url");
                            String media3_url = c.getString("media3_url");
                            String media4_url = c.getString("media4_url");
                            String created_at = c.getString("created_at");
                            String updated_at = c.getString("updated_at");
                            String like_status = c.getString("liked");
                            String follow_status = c.getString("follow");
                            if(caption.contentEquals("null")){
                                caption="";
                            }
                            HashMap<String, String> Info = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            Info.put("Post_id", id);
                            Info.put("username", username);
                            Info.put("user_id", user_id);
                            Info.put("Name", Name);
                            Info.put("caption", caption);
                            Info.put("media1_thumb_url", media1_thumb_url);
                            Info.put("media2_thumb_url", media2_thumb_url);
                            Info.put("media3_thumb_url", media3_thumb_url);
                            Info.put("media4_thumb_url", media4_thumb_url);
                            Info.put("media1_url", media1_url);
                            Info.put("media2_url", media2_url);
                            Info.put("media3_url", media3_url);
                            Info.put("media4_url", media4_url);
                            Info.put("created_at", created_at);
                            Info.put("updated_at", updated_at);
                            Info.put("likestatus", like_status);
                            Info.put("followstatus", follow_status);
                            data.add(Info);
                            Array_img.add(media1_url + "," + media2_url + "," + media3_url + "," + media4_url);
                            Array_single_image.add(media1_url);


//                      String userid = jsonnode.getString("user_id");
//                      Name = json_User.getString("name");
//                      access_tocken= jsonnode.getString("access_token");
//                      Ostype= jsonnode.getString("device_id");
                        }
                        // looping through All Contacts
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
            }


            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // Dismiss the progress dialog
            pDialog.dismiss();
            adapter = new SampleAdapter(getActivity(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data, Array_img,Array_single_image,
                    getActivity().getApplication());
//            RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
//            Lv.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
//            MyRecyclerAdapter adapter2 = new MyRecyclerAdapter(getActivity(), data,Array_img);

            Lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        //    Lv.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {

        }
    }

    public String makeServiceCall(String url) {
        String response = null;
        try {
            // http client
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpEntity httpEntity = null;
            HttpResponse httpResponse = null;

            // Checking http request method type

//              if (params != null) {
//                  String paramString = URLEncodedUtils
//                          .format(params, "utf-8");
//                  url += "?" + paramString;
//              }

            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
            httpGet.addHeader("X-TOKEN", accestoken);
            httpGet.addHeader("X-DEVICE", device_id);


            httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);


            httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return response;

    }
```

and this adapter class

```
public class SampleAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> implements
        OnClickListener {
    private static final String KEY_SELECTED_PAGE = "KEY_SELECTED_PAGE";
    private static final String KEY_SELECTED_CLASS = "KEY_SELECTED_CLASS";
    private static final ArrayList<TransformerItem> TRANSFORM_CLASSES;
    private static final String TAG = "SampleAdapter";

    private static Context contexts;
    private Application mAppContext;
    private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater = null;
    private Random mRandom;
    static String List_img;

    double km, lat_to, lon_to;
    String strlat_to, str_long_to;
    String Str_km = "";
    ImageLoader img_loader;
    private LruCache<String, Bitmap> mMemoryCache;

    private static final SparseArray<Double> sPositionHeightRatios = new SparseArray<Double>();

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> imagess = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    ArrayList<String> Array_imgadpter = new ArrayList<String>();

    static {
        TRANSFORM_CLASSES = new ArrayList<>();


        TRANSFORM_CLASSES.add(new TransformerItem(CubeOutTransformer.class));
        //TRANSFORM_CLASSES.add(new TransformerItem(CubeInTransformer.class));
    }

    private int mSelectedItem;

    private PageAdapter mAdapter;
    ArrayList<String> Array_single_image = new ArrayList<String>();
    static String[] items;

    public SampleAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                         ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> images, ArrayList<String> Array_img, ArrayList<String> Array_singr, Application app) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);
        this.mLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.mRandom = new Random();
        this.imagess = images;
        Array_single_image = Array_singr;
        mAppContext = app;
        //Array_imgadpter.clear();
        this.Array_imgadpter = Array_img;
        contexts = context;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                        final ViewGroup parent) {
        Resources mResources;
        final ViewHolder vh;
        final Context context = parent.getContext();
         img_loader = new ImageLoader(mAppContext);
         // if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_home_lv,
                parent, false);

        vh = new ViewHolder();
        vh.mPager = (viewpager) convertView.findViewById(R.id.container);
        vh.Name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView7);
        vh.Caption = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView10);
        vh.Circular_imagview = (CircularImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
        convertView.setTag(vh);
        //vh.mPager.setId(position + 1);
//         } else {
//            vh = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
////             vh.mPager.setId(position + 1);
//        }
//            vh.Circular_imagview.setBorderColor(mAppContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.Loginbg));
//            vh.Circular_imagview.setBorderWidth(5);
        vh.mPager.setId(position + 1);
        vh.mPager.setOnItemClickListener(new viewpager.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(int position) {
                int id = vh.mPager.getId();
                id = id - 1;
                String postion = String.valueOf(id);
                List_img = Array_imgadpter.get(id);
                String str_id =imagess.get(id).get("Post_id");
                String status_like=imagess.get(id).get("likestatus");
                String caption=imagess.get(id).get("caption");
                //Toast.makeText(mAppContext,"click "+id,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent lObjIntent = new Intent(mAppContext, Images_comment_screen.class);
                lObjIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                lObjIntent.putExtra("images",List_img);
                lObjIntent.putExtra("Post_id",str_id);
                lObjIntent.putExtra("status_like",status_like);
                lObjIntent.putExtra("caption",caption);
                mAppContext.startActivity(lObjIntent);
                //finish();
            }
        });
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        mResources = mAppContext.getResources();
        try {
            final Bitmap srcBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mResources, R.drawable.profile_placeholder);
            // Get source bitmap width and height

            int srcBitmapWidth = srcBitmap.getWidth();
            int srcBitmapHeight = srcBitmap.getHeight();

                /*
                    IMPORTANT NOTE : You should experiment with border and shadow width
                    to get better circular ImageView as you expected.
                    I am confused about those size.
                */
            // Define border and shadow width
            int borderWidth = 20;
            int shadowWidth = 0;

            // destination bitmap width
            int dstBitmapWidth = Math.min(srcBitmapWidth, srcBitmapHeight) + borderWidth * 2;
            //float radius = Math.min(srcBitmapWidth,srcBitmapHeight)/2;

            // Initializing a new bitmap to draw source bitmap, border and shadow

            Bitmap dstBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(dstBitmapWidth, dstBitmapWidth, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(dstBitmap);




            // Initialize a new canvas

            // Draw a solid color to canvas
            canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);

            // Draw the source bitmap to destination bitmap by keeping border and shadow spaces
            canvas.drawBitmap(srcBitmap, (dstBitmapWidth - srcBitmapWidth) / 2, (dstBitmapWidth - srcBitmapHeight) / 2, null);

            // Use Paint to draw border
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            paint.setStrokeWidth(borderWidth * 2);
            paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);

            // Draw the border in destination bitmap
            canvas.drawCircle(canvas.getWidth() / 2, canvas.getHeight() / 2, canvas.getWidth() / 2, paint);

            // Use Paint to draw shadow
            paint.setColor(Color.LTGRAY);
            paint.setStrokeWidth(shadowWidth);

            // Draw the shadow on circular bitmap
            canvas.drawCircle(canvas.getWidth() / 2, canvas.getHeight() / 2, canvas.getWidth() / 2, paint);

                /*
                    RoundedBitmapDrawable
                        A Drawable that wraps a bitmap and can be drawn with rounded corners. You
                        can create a RoundedBitmapDrawable from a file path, an input stream, or
                        from a Bitmap object.
                */
            // Initialize a new RoundedBitmapDrawable object to make ImageView circular
            RoundedBitmapDrawable roundedBitmapDrawable = RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(mResources, dstBitmap);

                /*
                    setCircular(boolean circular)
                        Sets the image shape to circular.
                */
            // Make the ImageView image to a circular image
            roundedBitmapDrawable.setCircular(true);

                /*
                    setAntiAlias(boolean aa)
                        Enables or disables anti-aliasing for this drawable.
                */
            roundedBitmapDrawable.setAntiAlias(true);

            // Set the ImageView image as drawable object
            vh.Circular_imagview.setImageDrawable(roundedBitmapDrawable);
        }catch (OutOfMemoryError error){
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
        //convertView.setTag(vh);

        //int selectedPage = 0;
        //vh.mPager.setId(position + 1);
        try {
            vh.mPager.setPageTransformer(true, TRANSFORM_CLASSES.get(0).clazz.newInstance());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }




        //mPager.setCurrentItem(selectedPage);
        List_img = Array_imgadpter.get(position);
        vh.Name.setText(imagess.get(position).get("username"));
        vh.Caption.setText(imagess.get(position).get("caption"));
        vh.mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
                int positionn = vh.mPager.getId();
                positionn = positionn - 1;
                String postion = String.valueOf(positionn);
                List_img = Array_imgadpter.get(positionn);
                items = List_img.split(",");

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                int positionn = vh.mPager.getId();
                positionn = positionn - 1;
                String postion = String.valueOf(positionn);
                List_img = Array_imgadpter.get(positionn);

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

                int positionn = vh.mPager.getId();
                positionn = positionn - 1;
                String postion = String.valueOf(positionn);
                List_img = Array_imgadpter.get(positionn);


            }


        });




        FragmentManager fm = ((Activity) context).getFragmentManager();

        mAdapter = new PageAdapter(fm);

        vh.mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        return convertView;
    }


    static class ViewHolder {
        ImageView imgView, star1, star2, star3, star4;
        TextView Name, Caption, fixed_meal, price, rating, distance, TxtVw_Afterdiscount, Txtvw;
        Button BTN_DETAIL;
        private viewpager mPager;
        Button button2;
        CircularImageView Circular_imagview;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return imagess.size();
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//        int positionn = vh.mPager.getId();
//        positionn = positionn - 1;
//        String postion = String.valueOf(positionn);
//        List_img = Array_imgadpter.get(positionn);
//        Intent intent = new Intent(mAppContext, Images_comment_screen.class);
//        intent.putExtra("images", List_img);
//
//
//        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
//        mAppContext.startActivity(intent);
        Toast.makeText(mAppContext, "click", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    private static final class TransformerItem {

        final String title;
        final Class<? extends ViewPager.PageTransformer> clazz;

        public TransformerItem(Class<? extends ViewPager.PageTransformer> clazz) {
            this.clazz = clazz;
            title = clazz.getSimpleName();
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return title;
        }

    }

    public class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        private static final String EXTRA_POSITION = "EXTRA_POSITION";
        //private  final int[] COLORS = new int[]{R.drawable.imgone, R.drawable.imgtwo, R.drawable.imgthree, R.drawable.imgfour};

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            final int position = getArguments().getInt(EXTRA_POSITION);
            final ImageView textViewPosition = (ImageView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

            items = List_img.split(",");
            String url = items[position];

            try {
                Picasso.with(contexts).load(items[position]).placeholder(R.drawable.placeholderdevzillad).into(textViewPosition);
                //
               // img_loader.DisplayImage(url,textViewPosition);
            } catch (OutOfMemoryError error) {

            }


            //textViewPosition.setBackgroundResource(COLORS[position]);
            return textViewPosition;
        }


    }

    private class PageAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

        public PageAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
            super(fragmentManager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            final Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putInt(PlaceholderFragment.EXTRA_POSITION, position);

            final PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            fragment.setArguments(bundle);

            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 4;
        }

    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some suggestions:

1. You haven't recycle your ListView item, in your `SampleAdapter`-`getView`, convertView is not reused if it is not null.
2. Don't need to use Fragment as your ViewPager item, just use ViewGroup as ViewPager's item.
3. For more, I think you can Define a Recycled PagerAdapter to manage and recycle all the items in different ViewPagers of different ListView item.

Forgive my bad English, and hope this is helpful for you.

Comment: thanks for suggestion,can you share example ,for better understanding